# How to find if the device is having rounded corners and if so, how to find its radius in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to find the corner radius of the display in Andriod , is there a way to find out?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. I think displays are essentially considered rectangles with safe areas. You can look at the [`SafeArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) widget, which is the best that we get for avoiding these areas.